# How can I use JOOQ's insertInto with multiple values? (Sybase Database)

Tags: sybase, jooq

I get an exception when I try to insert multiple values into a Sybase Database with JOOQ:

**Java Code:**

```
dsl.insertInto(ACTIVITY).columns(ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_NO, ACTIVITY.SUMMARY)
    .values(1, "summary 1")
    .values(2, "summary 2")
    .execute()
```

**Is turned into SQL:**

```
org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Executing query          : insert into [activity] ([activity_NO], [summary]) select * from (select ?, ?) x union all select * from (select ?, ?) x
org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - -> with bind values      : insert into [activity] ([activity_NO], [summary]) select * from (select 1, 'summary 1') x union all select * from (select 2, 'summary 2') x

insert into ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_NO, SUMMARY)
select *
from (select 1, 'summary 1') x
union all
select *
from (select 2, 'summary 2') x
```

**Results in the Exception:**

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into [activity] ([activity_NO], [summary]) select * from (select ?, ?) x union all select * from (select ?, ?) x]; A derived table expression may not have null column names. Use a derived column list in the derived table definition or name the column expressions in the SELECT target list.
```

The Exception comes from the Sybase Database: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/sqlug423.htm

**The correct SQL would be:**

```
insert into ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_NO, SUMMARY)
select *
from (select 1 as ACTIVITY_NO, 'summary 1' as SUMMARY) x
union all
select *
from (select 2 as ACTIVITY_NO, 'summary 2' as SUMMARY) x
```

How can I handle this problem with JOOQ?

Comment: Which Sybase is this (ASE or SQL Anywhere) and what version?

Comment: Hi Lukas. We have a Sybase ASE Version 15.7